# jsf 2 project structure

Tags: jsf-2

Does any expert here have any particular preference for a JSF 2's project structure. Currently, I have the following:

```
root
  Java Resources: src
     dao.au.com.xyz
     model.au.com.xyz
  ant
  WebContent
     META-INF
     resources
        css
        javascript
        images
     WEB-INF
     sections (for common sections like: menu, header, footers)
     templates (common templates)
     views (xhtml pages)
     index.html (redirect to index.xhtml under views folder)
```

Is this structure reasonable/valid for a JSF 2 (Facelets) project structure? I couldn't find anything in the JSF specification close to what I want.

Comment: The folder is called WebContent right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's subjective and personal and more dependent on the [Servlet API specification](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr315/index.html). As long as the exported WAR conforms the directory structure as specified in the servlet specification and it is in your/team's opinion the best useable and maintainable, then it's fine.

I would however prefer the [standard Java conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html) with regard to package names. Go from big to small, not the other way round or even mixed. E.g. `com.example.model` and so on instead of `model.com.example`.